# How to make a Grid inside another CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to make a Grid inside another Grid but it wont work.
I tried even Flexbox but its like my porevious Grid overwrite everything, like im giving non-existent code, what am i missing?
Also, i'm trying to make the Inner Grid inside a Carousel (slick-js), maybe it is that what its giving me problems?

I tried to make the inner CSS Grid not in a Grid-Area and it wouldnt work, i'm out of options for myself.

```css
#landing{
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px repeat(6, 1fr) 40px;
  grid-template-rows: 40px repeat(6, 1fr) 40px;
  font-size: 1em;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "x-t-l . . . . . . x-t-r"
  ". . . . . . . ."
  ". . . . . prev . ."
  ". . . . . . . ."
  ". . . . . . . ."
  ". . . . . next . ."
  ". . . . . . info ."
  "x-b-l . . . . . . x-b-r";
}

#carousel{
  display: flex;
  grid-column: 3 / 7;
  grid-row: 4 / 6;
  background-color: rgb(219, 15, 15) ;
  color: white;
}

.roller-a{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.title{
  grid-column: 1;
}

.box{
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-top-left"></div>
<div class="x-top-right"></div>

<div id="carousel">

<div class="roller-a">
  <div class="title">TEST</div>
  <div class="box">TEST 2</div>
</div>

<div class="roller-b">
  <div>TEST 3</div>
  <div>TEST 4</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="buttons slick-next">
  <button type="button" class="slick-next">UP</button>
</div>

<div class="buttons slick-prev">    
  <button type="button" class="slick-prev">DOWN</button>
</div>

<div class="info"> 
  <img class="logo" src="../New/img/logo.png" alt="">
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <p>TEXT</p> 
</div>

<div class="x-bot-left"></div>
<div class="x-bot-right"></div>
```

I expected a Grid inside a Grid with

```
.roller-a{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

But it wont make one.

Thank you in advance, this thing gave an headache.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdZgrL

Comment: @NoriSte https://codepen.io/DoKuStudio/pen/omdeWO ALRIGHT. I've noticed that i CODEPEN it does actually work! But that's because i didnt load Slick JS, so, that thing is not letting me another grid inside, is there anyway to surpass this problem? I wanted to make a vertical carousel with some sections

Comment: Could you add Slick JS to the Codepen too? So we can inspect what changes SlickJS applies to the DOM and analyze them

Comment: @NoriSte Updated,https://codepen.io/DoKuStudio/pen/omdeWO As you can see now that i have applied the Slick the Grid Columns are gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slick (as every slider library) updates the DOM, it transforms your DOM from

```
<div class="carousel">

    <div class="roller-a">
        <div class="title">TEST</div>
        <div class="box">TEST 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="roller-b">
        <div>TEST 3</div>
        <div>TEST 4</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

to

```
<div class="carousel slick-initialized slick-slider slick-vertical">

    <div class="slick-list draggable" style="height: 34px;">
        <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; height: 68px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <div class="roller-a slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" style="width: 905px;">
                <div class="title">TEST</div>
                <div class="box">TEST 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="roller-b slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="width: 905px;">
                <div>TEST 3</div>
                <div>TEST 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

or, if you prefer a visual comparison
[image]

What brokes your grid is mostly (but not only) the styles applied by

```
.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
    display: block;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
    display: block;
}
```

so if you want your double grid working with Slick you must override there CSS properties and check that everything works.